# Rest client framework for complex objects

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, jersey-client

I have developed one web service for order management. This web service takes many complex objects as input parameters. I used curl to test and it works fine. Now I am writing a client but ***having issue when for ArrayList*** (e.g. the items are coming as ArrayList) objects. It's sending as String. It's seems the limitation the client framework I am using. I have tried one or two open frameworks but they are not working as expected. It will be great if you can suggest some framework with some examples.

Below is the sample curl request, I have removed some extra parameters to keep it simple.

> curl -L -v -b agent_cookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
>   "{"items":{"atg-rest-class-type":"java.util.ArrayList","atg-rest-values":
>   [{"atg-rest-class-type":"com.bean.CommerceItemInfo","tinSkuNumber":"41589367","itemNumber":
>   280594,"color": 9,"size":
>   94,"salePrice":50.00,"taxAmount":3.5,"stateTax":0.48,"countyTax":0.08,"currencyCode":"USD"},{"atg-rest-class-type":"com..bean.CommerceItemInfo",
>   "tinSkuNumber":"41589375","itemNumber": 280594,"color": 9,"size":
>   96,"salePrice":100.00,"taxAmount":7,"stateTax":0.96,"countyTax":0.16,"currencyCode":"USD"}]},orderInfo:{...},"clientAddress":{"atg-rest-class-type":"java.util.ArrayList","atg-rest-values":
>   [{"atg-rest-class-type":"com.bean.ClientAddress",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Dao\",\"state\":\"FL\",\"country\":\"US\",\"postalCode\":\"33606\",\"address1\":\"100
>   S Edison Avenue\",\"address2\":\"Suite
>   D\",\"city\":\"Tampa\",\"addressType\":\"BOTH\"}]},{......}}"
>   http://localhost:8080/rest/model/com/web/actor/CartActor/testOrder

Thank you

Comment: In case you want to deserialize `"atg-rest-class-type":"java.util.ArrayList","atg-rest-values":  [{"atg-rest-class-type":"com.bean.CommerceItemInfo"...` into an `ArrayList<CommerceItemInfo>` you'll either have to use that odd atg framework that invented this terrible serialization format or write a whole lot of code that does this or use a proper restful format that is not attempting to be a java serializer.

Comment: True, this atg framewrok sucks. I have tried the atg client but I it's not able to convert custom beans. Can you please provide one example.

Comment: For what exactly? Custom deserializers with jax-rs?

Comment: No..example with atg frameowrk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the limitation of ATG client and  no way we can send List.I changed the arguments to accept individual beans only.